# How can I set cucumber feature path using a string from another class?

Tags: java, cucumber

here's my question:
I'd like to set the '**features**' path on my cucumber configuration class using a string from another class. I have a lot of different tests and I always need to change the feature path manually in each one, I already tried to create another class with a string, where I can set the paths that I use most (because I work on two different laptops), but I couldn't call the string inside the @CucumberOptions annotation. Is there some way to do it?

The way it is now:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

        plugin = {"json:../evidence/output/report_data.json", "html:../evidence/output/"}
        , features = {"../feature/finish_orders.feature"}
```

The way I want it

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

        plugin = {"json:../evidence/output/report_data.json", "html:../evidence/output/"}
        , features = {STRING_WHERE_IS_THE_PATH}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have all your feature files stored in one place. It does not have to be the same directory and can be nested. If you want to execute a specific scenario you can use tagging. For example, you can set your `@CucumberOptions` like this:

```
@CucumberOptions(
             features = {"classpath:test_features"}, 
             tags = {"@wip"})
```

and tag the scenarios you want to run with `@wip`. It will only execute the `@wip` tagged scenarios.